# Vim: how to make :q shut up about unvisited files?

Tags: multiple-files, quit

When Vim is invoked on multiple files from the command line, then if any of those files have not been visited with `:next` or via buffer switching, the `:q` command pointlessly warns about the situation with a message like "43 files left to edit" and refuses to quit, even though nothing has been modified. Is there a way to eliminate this behavior?

In the `:help` documentation, we have:

```
:q[uit]             Quit the current window.  Quit Vim if this is the last
                    window.  This fails when changes have been made and
                    Vim refuses to abandon the current buffer, and when
                    the last file in the argument list has not been
                    edited.
                    If there are other tab pages and quitting the last
                    window in the current tab page the current tab page is
                    closed tab-page.
                    Triggers the QuitPre autocommand event.
                    See CTRL-W_q for quitting another window.
```

which just confirms the behavior: "fails ... when the last file in the argument list has not been edited".

The forced execution `:q!` will work, but is not acceptable because it will discard unsaved changes.

**The documentation does not seem to mention that if the command fails due to the last file not having been edited, simply repeating the command will then force it.**

Comment: Perhaps `set confirm`? I think then you can choose to quit anyway

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Experimenting with `:set confirm`, I can confirm that I like it better than `:qa`, because there is no new habit to learn. You just hit `y` in response and you're out: same character count as `:qa`. Still, I like the solution which just make `:q` work. Thanks though, I will turn on `confirm` because it provides a good UX for unsaved-changes situations.

Comment: Looking at the source, it seems there isn't an option for that right now; there is just a check for the `confirm` option and that's it. (`check_more()` in `ex_docmd.c`). It wouldn't be too hard to add an option for this (or expand `confirm` to accept more values) though, but that requires someone to write a patch, so if you're willing/able to spend some time on that you can fix it "properly". Other than that, there's just the workarounds you already posted.

Answer (score 3):

The `:cabbrev`-answer has downsides because the abbreviation is active everywhere in the `:` command line, even if restricted to that type of command using the `<expr>` mechanism.

Ideally, Vim would have a command execution hook: a piece of code that could be executed each time a command is run, or at least an interactive command. That hook could rewrite the command.

Turns out, we can use `:autocmd` as a close facsimile. Vim's `:autocmd` has useful hooks, one of which is `QuitPre`. And so, with this simple line in the `.vimrc`, all seems good:

```
:au QuitPre * qa
```

When the `QuitPre` event is triggered on any buffer, we issue the `qa` command. This effectively rewrites `q` to `qa`.

Various experiments are confirming to me that it has the right behavior, and fixes `:x` also. When multiple files are being edited, and there are no changes, both `:x` and `:q` quit, as desired.

When there are unsaved changes, `:q` still fails, and `:x` fails if other buffers are unsaved.

A curious behavior occurs with `:q!`, though all seems well nonetheless. When there are unsaved changes, it quits as expected. However, Vim's admonishments that there are unsaved changes briefly flash on the display for a fraction of a second.

Comment: This is definitely a better approach! Glad you found it. I still think the warning is useful and `:qa` is not too painful, but at least this doesn't have the shortcomings of `cabbrev`...

Comment: @filbranden Can you explain how the warning useful? If I were to complete the sentence "If it were not for that warning, then _____" I can hardly think of a "bad thing" to fill in the blank. I've never used any desktop application where you could have multiple document windows open that will refuse to quit if none of them have unsaved changes, based on some of the windows not having been raised to the foreground. All I can think of is that if you open multiple files with the *intent* to make certain changes, you might inadvertently quit without fulfilling the intent. Or something.

Comment: If you're editing a large number of files, it could be annoying to return to the correct one after inadvertently quitting. You have to `:ls` to list the buffers to locate that file, and `:b<n>` to jump to it by number.  In other regards, Vim preserves the state, like the contents registers, and whatnot. You should be able to pick up the edit session. Still, someone who does that to themselves habitually will probably be spared some effort thanks to that warning.  I think you lose your last command. If you're repeating something with `.` over the files, that goes away if you inadvertently quit.

Comment: If I open a list of files, it means I plan to look or modify them all (at least at first.) For example, `vim src/*/*.[ch]` and then add a copyright notice or license at the top of all files, or `vim $(grep -r foo)` to replace `foo` with `bar` or perhaps manually refactor all the code that's using `foo` everywhere. In those cases, the warning that I didn't go through the whole list is surely useful. Sure, I *might* want to bail out early (in which case `:qa` is adequate.)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative is to `:set confirm`. Then `:q` will prompt in this case, and you hit `y` (or a localized equivalent) to continue. No new habits.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a better solution than `:au QuitPre * qa`.

Vim's complaint that unedited files remain is not literally based on that stated condition. The internal condition is actually "has the last file been visited"?

So that is to say, if we open a bunch of files:

```
vim *.c
```

and then do this:

```
:last
:q
```

it will quit. The warning:

```
E173: 57 more files to edit.
```

is not a lie *per se*, but it is misleading about the condition on which it is based. It should really say:

```
E173: There are 57 unvisited files and you've not visited the last one.
```

And so, the following solution presents itself:

```
:au QuitPre * last
```

That's it! Before quitting, run the `:last` command to visit the last file.

I have tested this and have not noticed any side effects. For a brief moment, you may catch glimpse of the editor's status line switching to showing the name of the last file before just prior to termination.

I discovered a funny thing while experimenting with this.

If you start Vim with no file argument at all (no file is being edited, just a buffer), the `:last` command produces this diagnostic:

```
E163: There is only one file to edit
```

E163 should say:

```
E163: No files are being edited, therefore there is no last file
```

No such error is not produced if you edit exactly one file and use `:last`, which makes sense: if you're editing one file, that's the last file.

In any case, even with the `au QuitPre * last` installed, I've not seen even the slightest glimpse of this E163 error message when quitting a no-file edit session.

**Edit:** An unwanted side effect of `:au QuitPre last` has been discovered, which is quite nasty.

I sometimes edit a fairly large file of more than 80,000 lines, for which the `BufEnter` action runs a custom Vim script for folding calculations. This takes a bit of time to run.

Now, when I save the file and exit with `:x`, there is a big delay.

If I take out the `:au QuitPre last` from my `.vimrc`, then `:x` is virtually instant.

It seems that Vim does not optimize `:last` when that is a no-op; it is behaving as if entering that buffer.

I can reproduce this issue by typing `:last`. Vim freezes for many seconds, even though nothing is being edited but that file.

An acceptable solution to this problem must avoid this side effect. Perhaps the command dispatched by `QuitPre` should be a conditional which executes `last` only if there are two or more buffers.

That solution is this:

```
:au QuitPre blast
```

Switching to the last buffer using `:bl{ast}` rather than `:last` does not exhibit the above problem. With `bl`, Vim does not re-execute the time-consuming folding-related scriptology if that buffer is already the one being edited. Yet this `QuitPre` hook still has the desired effect of suppressing the warning about unvisited files.

Comment: `au QuitPre blast` should be `au QuitPre * blast`. I'd edit, but SO is forcing me to change at least 6 characters and there is nothing else to improve :(

Comment: @MartinvonWittich Looking into my `.vimrc`, I see that I have it as `au QuitPre * blast`. Not sure what happened here.

Answer (score 0):

The `:qa` command does what I want.

By itself, that would not be an acceptable solution; however, it's possible to turn `:q` into `:qa` using

```
:cabbrev q qa
```

This accompanying definition also helps:

```
:cabbrev x xa
```

allowing `:x` to be used to save and quit a change even though there are unedited buffers.

Unfortunately, the abbreviatiosn are active throughout the `:` command line and other contexts. Based on user [filbranden](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/18609/filbranden)'s excellent hint in the comments below, the following refinement ensures that the abbreviations are only expanded in a colon command:

```
:cabbrev <expr> q (getcmdtype()==":"?"qa":"q")
:cabbrev <expr> x (getcmdtype()==":"?"xa":"x")
```

This achieves the effect as if the abbreviation didn't exist outside of the `:` command line. Still, the mitigation is not perfect because `q`, if it appears as a delimited in the right ways, expands to `qa` almost anywhere in the command line. If we try to edit a file called `q` using:

```
:vi q
```

the abbreviation expands and `qa` is opened instead.

Comment: Folks, this was headed into discussion territory, so I [moved it to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125042/discussion-on-answer-by-kaz-vim-how-to-make-q-shut-up-about-unvisited-files). Let's take any further discussion that way, though it looked like things were dying out. Here's also a gentle reminder of the [Be Nice](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) policy. I don't see anything in here that's overtly rude, and I'm sure we can find ways to constructively express ourselves without words like "idiotic." We appreciate helpful contributions to the site.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble In fact, "I made the point I wanted to make" signified the end of the discussion as far as I was concerned. The only reason I'm here right now was I noticed some missing comments in my history. It's not clear to me what parts of your comment are for me...I'm hoping it's "none" since I'm well beyond the age where I need "adult supervision". ;) Probably quite a few beyond when you no longer needed it.